# Mongoid fields issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am working on dynamic form generator. And I've noticed strange behaviour

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
end

model = Model.new
model.name = "My Name"
model.surname = "My Surname"
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `surname='
```

but

```
model = Model.new( :name => "My Name", :surname => "My Surname" )
#=> ok
model.surname
#=> "My Surname"
model.surname = "New Surname"
#=> "New Surname"
```

Can somebody explain why I can create new fields with mass assignment and can't add fields through attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the Mongoid documentation, the getter/setter methods (e.g. `.surname`) will only work if the field exists in the document (which is why when you create a new `Model` with the field, it works).

You can still set/read the fields like so:

```
model[:surname]
model.read_attribute(:surname)
model[:surname] = "My Surname"
model.write_attribute(:surname, "My Surname")
```

See http://mongoid.org/docs/documents/dynamic.html

Comment: that is the same functionality: `model[:surname] = "My Surname"` and `model.write_attribute(:surname, "My Surname")`. What is the difference? I've just tested - looks pretty same, but there is no comments in that docs article

Comment: The source code has `alias :[] :read_attribute`, so they are exactly the same (same with `[]=` and `write_attribute`). Just use the one you prefer.